# Изменить права на папки в Linux

Tags: linux, chmod, chown

Вопрос избитый...Какие права выставлять на папки и файлы в линуксе?И как задать от какого пользователя выполняются файлы? Как узнать текущего пользователя через PHP скрипт?Можете привести последовательность команд? Юзаю CentOs 6.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Узнать какие права и владелец:

```
ls -lsah
```

Поменять права:

```
chmod
man chmod
```

Поменять пользователя:

```
chown
man chown
```

Comment: Вот результат первой команды:4.0K drwxr-xr-x  7 whois nobody   4.0K Jul  8 02:37 ./4.0K drwx--x--x 11 whois whois 4.0K Jul  7 15:46 ../4.0K drwxr-xr-x 15 root     root     4.0K Jul  8 02:36 application/4.0K drwxr-xr-x  2 whois whois 4.0K Jul  5 14:58 cgi-bin/

Comment: Как я понял, у меня одни каталоги от рута используются, другие от имени whois.

Comment: Прошу выложить в отформатированном виде вывод      Пропускаем 1 строку и ставим 4 пробела    И еще конец строки это 2 пробела